# Html5 Canvas : Rotated text looks distorted on Google Chrome

Tags: windows, html, google-chrome, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have rotated a text in HTML5 canvas. It looks fine on all the browsers except google chrome. It looks distorted on chrome on Windows. Also, it looks fine on MAC. Why is it so?
I am using Chrome beta 20. Is it some HTML 5 issue or some Google Chrome or Windows bug? How can I resolve this distortion issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #myCanvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.font = "12pt Calibri";
        context.rotate(Math.PI/2.5);
        context.fillText("Competitive Landcaping!", 450, 100);
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="878" height="2000"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the same head-banging myself recently. The short answer is that Chrome renders fonts quite poorly on Windows, and transformed fonts just get worse from there.

For a longer, more technical answer, check this post:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/

There isn't a whole to be done about it, apart from trying to pick fonts that look the 'least worst' in Chrome.